# How to override content_type "Article"?

Tags: nodes, entities

I want to add some fields (programmatically from my module) to the content_type "Article".

Is that possible ?

Comment: why do you want to add fields to article type programmatically when you can easily do it using Field UI by navigating **Admin => Structure => Content Types => Articles => Manage Fields**?

Answer (score 0):

Use [hook_entity_bundle_field_info()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal!Core!Entity!entity.api.php/function/hook_entity_bundle_field_info/8)

Copying from the api docs

```
function mymodule_entity_bundle_field_info(\Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityTypeInterface $entity_type, $bundle, array $base_field_definitions) {
  // Add a property only to nodes of the 'article' bundle.
  if ($entity_type->id() == 'node' && $bundle == 'article') {
    $fields = array();
    $fields['mymodule_text_more'] = BaseFieldDefinition::create('string')
      ->setLabel(t('More text'))
      ->setComputed(TRUE)
      ->setClass('\Drupal\mymodule\EntityComputedMoreText');
    return $fields;
  }
}
```

Comment: Should be noted this answer is for Drupal 8. OP doesn't say what version is being used or why the admin UI can't be used.